# Printers not visible in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, printer

When in MS Word or PowerPoint, when I go to File → Print, I can see all the printers. But when I do the same thing in Excel, no printers are installed. Yet I can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> shortcut keys and it does print. So the printer is there, it's just not showing up.

What could be the problem and how can I fix this?

Comment: Knowing what OS you are using and what version of Office will help someone answer your question. Please [edit] your question with additional details.

Comment: You could try repairing the Office installation in your control panel.

Comment: You know...it could be something as simple as your scroll bar for the printer selection is moved over to the right and therefore you don't see the other printers. If there is a scroll bar, can you move it to the left? I know it's simple, but hey, it's a possibility.

Answer (score 3):

here is the following step which is solve my problem you can also try this

Printer not show in excel 2007

Please do the following steps

1. Open regedit
2. Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER  -> software  -> Microsoft -> WindowsNT ->
3. Here you  find the three folder Devices , Printer Ports and Windows
4. Right click on every folder and give the full permission for the user in which you show this problem
5. Restart the system
6. And reinstall the printer

May be your problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on Windows XP with Excel 97.  In my case the print spooler service had failed to start on boot (even though it is set to "Automatic").

I found the error about the print spooler when I tried to delete my printer (with plans to reinstall it to see if that would help) and got the message that the printer could not be deleted because the spooler service was not running.

I did this:

- Press "Window key" + "R" to open the Run dialog
- Type "services.msc", then click "OK"
- Find the print spooler service in the list
- If it is not running, right-click on it and choose "Start"

And then I was able to print from Excel again.

**Edit** I got a message that another user had a similar problem, but their print spooler was listed as running.  In their case stopping it (right-click and "Stop") followed by restarting fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and found a simple solution.

The reason seems to be that Excel and Acrobat are looking for a default printer. For some reason it appeared not possible to set a default printer on my 2008 Vista (hahahaha) laptop. This problem is known by Microsoft who have a complicated  solution for this, but I found a more simple one.
For this you will have to start the Control Panel in administrator mode.
To do this, go to Windows/System32/control.exe. Right click and choose for
'run as administrator'. Open the 'Printers' option and you will be able to set a default printer. Now Excel and Acrobat (and probably all other programs) can connect to your printer.

Answer (score 0):

- Open regedit
- Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> software -> Microsoft -> WindowsNT
- Here you find the three folder Devices , Printer Ports and Windows
- Right click on every folder and give the full permission for the user in which - you show this problem
- Restart the system
- Reinstall the printer

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem: printers weren't showing up on Word and Adobe.

To fix this, do the following:

- Go to Device Manager and right-click for `Properties` on the printer.
- Go to the `Settings` tab and click the `Devices and Printers` folder.
- Next, right-click any printer and select `Troubleshooting`.

This will restart the service for the printers and will fix any frozen USB port.

Answer (score -1):

If the printer is visible in word but not in excel, first you will have to login to the Administrator account and take backup of User profile then follow these steps:

1. Go to the My computer Management
2. Click on Local user and Group > click on User in Right hand Side
3. Delete the User Profile.
4. Create again User account with previous User Name

Now your Printer will visible in Excel and Pdf

Comment: While your answer might solve the issue it seems to be overkill. Also nowadays with so often malware attacks it's a very bad practice to use an admin account on a daily basis.

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:

- Restart your PC and press <kbd>F8</kbd>
- Go to "Safe mode with command prompt"
- Type in the following commands, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each one

  ```
  attrib -s -h -r user.dat

  attrib -s -h -r user.da0

  ren user.dat user.old

  ren user.da0 user.dat
  ```
- Finally type `exit` and restart your PC.

Comment: So let me get this straight - you think the OP uses **Windows 95**?